# Jquery Dialog box scrolls to a link, how to keep it at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dialogbox that shows the contents of an HTML file.
In this file there is a href link at the bottom.
Now everytime the dialog is shown, it automatically scrolls to that link and sets focus to it.

How can I set the scroll position back to the top after the dialog shows?

Here is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() 
  {
    $('#faq1_pnM').dialog( 
    { 
      title: 'Frequently asked questions', 
      autoOpen: false, 
      modal: true, 
      show: 'puff', 
      hide: 'puff', 
      open: function() { 
        var e1 = $(this); 
        var scrollY = this.scrollHeight; 
        e1.scrollTop(scrollY); 
        e1.parent().queue(function(next) { 
          e1.scrollTop(scrollY); 
          next(); 
         });
       },
      resizable: false, 
      closeOnEscape: true,
      width: '650',
      height: '500',
      minWidth: '500',
      minHeight: '500'
    }).dialog('open'); 
 });
</script>
```

As you can see, I tried with the open: function... stuff, but that doesn't do the trick.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I see it opening? http://jsfiddle.net/77qo10dj/3/ What is happening when you do it? Can you add a JSFiddle?

Comment: It opens, that is right. The problem is it scrolls to the bottom where a link is in the html. I want it to open with the scrollbar at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

I removed the scrollY variable and replaced it for 0 (zero).

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and this solved my issue. Appears to be strange behaviour in jQuery dialog.